# Any faster solution for Powershell.Invoke?

Tags: c#, json, powershell

I'm writing a CmdLet in C# and use the [Powershell-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and invoke different commands. Here my Code:

```
PowerShell poswershell;
public Construcor()
{
     powershell = PowerShell.Create()
}
public Collection<PSObject> InvokeRestMethod(string uri)
{
    return InvokePSCommand("Invoke-RestMethod", new[] { uri });
}

public Collection<PSObject> InvokePSCommand(string command, string[] args)
{
    var execute = command;
    execute = GetExecuteCommand(args, execute);
    powershell.Commands.AddScript(execute);
    return powershell.Invoke();

}

private static string GetExecuteCommand(string[] args, string execute)
{
    if (args == null) return execute;
    for (var i = 0; i < args.Count(); i++)
    {
        execute += " " + args[i];
    }
    return execute;
}
```

It works like I want, but really slowly. I want the same function, which gives me a `Collection<PSObject>` back. But when I call the [`InvokeRestMehtod`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx) several times, it takes a long time to get trough this.
Why I use this just for a simple `WebRequest` you ask? 
The answer is, that I have to read from an uri (which returns [`json`](http://www.json.org/)) some information. Fact is that the `json` structure is always different. Therefor the `Invoke-RestMehtod` gives me exactly what I need, a dynamic object([`PSObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I have to have this kind of object, because after that process I need to give this in the powershell user back, so he can pipeline the object and use it furhter.
My question is now, how could I get the same result, which I can pass into powershell, from an uri which return `json`?

***EDIT***

I found this dll=> `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll`, it includes in `C#` code the `InvokeRestMethod`-CmdLet what is called by the `powershell`. If I could read this code well, I could (would) use it in my code. Then I wouldn't create a PowerShell instance and invoke from my powershell-CmdLet an other CmdLet, which I do not like much and takes a way too long. Someone knows this `dll` and could help me to customize this code for my project?

I found [dottrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/,) and analyzed the process, here a [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/g0z4ji1et) I can't get any useful information out of that, perhaps someone of you? But I'm pretty sure `Powershell.Invoke()` takes most of the time while executing.

Comment: It won't speed things up much, but you don't need your GetExecuteCommandFunction in your example, instead write powershell.AddCommand(command);  foreach (var arg in args) { powershell.AddArgument(arg); }  This avoids generating a script and also avoids running any parsing of the command by PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for you comment I will make this change. But it's not the solution of my problem. I search an other way to get the same result, because the line `powershell.Invoke();` takes too long in executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now, here is the basic code which reads an uri (returns `JSON`) and returns an `object`:

```
  private object InvokeRest(string uri)
    {
        return InvokeRest(uri, null);
    }
    private object InvokeRest(string uri, NetworkCredential networkCredential)
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        if (networkCredential!=null)
            webRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
        _webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(_webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        ErrorRecord exRef;
        var doc = JsonObject.ConvertFromJson(str, out exRef);
        return doc;
    }
```

Because I found out that every `object` you output in the powershell, converts in a `PSObject` and formats it.

Comment: What is the full namespace of JsonObject.ConvertFromJson()?

Comment: @FuyuPersimmon [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JsonObject located inside this assembly: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.jsonobject.convertfromjson(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you reuse the same PowerShell object rather than create a new one each time? Each instantiation causes the PowerShell to have to initialize again. Just be sure to call powershell.Commands.Clear() between Invoke() calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I made this useful change, thanks mate. But in the speed nothing changed, in debugging I have seen on the line `powershell.Invoke();` it takes a long time. Each `Invoke` takes about 2 seconds.